# What is the proper definition of a verb?

Tags: terminology, linguistic-typology, verbs, theoretical-linguistics, parts-of-speech

*I do apologise if the question is wordy, but I feel some context is required for me to stand any chance of finding a satifactory answer.*

I have been struggling to understand why the word "is" counts as a verb in English. This lead me to search for what verbs actually are rather than the naive definition I was given in school (doing words). I didn't study English beyond highschool, but I am a first language speaker.
I suspect that most speakers would recognise

> The sky is blue
> .

as a grammatically correct clause, but it always seemed to me that the word "is" was simply defined to be a verb in order to force the rule that all clauses must contain a verb. This is really the crux of the question. I found the following definition:

> *A verb is a word that in syntax conveys an action, occurence, or state of being.*

Even on the surface of it this definition must be wrong because several sources tell me that "to be" is a verb despite it being two words and not **a word**, but so far the gist of it seems to agree with other searches I've done. From what I can tell, an action is a cause for a change in state and occurences are just actions in the past tense so it makes sense to me that they would be lumped them together in a category.
What I don't understand is why states of being are included, since they seem to me to be inherently passive which I understand to be the exact opposite of being active. I've seen the term "state of being verb" used in some explanations, but this only reinforced the idea that a state of being is a separate category to an action.

Have I misunderstood what an action is? Are the definitions I've found just hideously wrong? Or is there something else (besides an education) I'm just missing?

Comment: Good question, especially for this site!

Comment: Who are you asking for a definition? Me? Obama? None of us have "authority" to define a word. There will always be different definitions in dictionaries and everyone has their own interpretation.

Comment: [Relevant tweet](https://web.archive.org/web/20220218093104/http://twitter.com/ItsMattTyler/status/1290959912210702337)

Comment: If one of your issues is that "to be" is two words, then why select only that verb? How about "to run", "to sleep", "to jump", ..., ?

Comment: Note that while "to be" is considered the un-conjugated form of "is", "am", etc., it isn't typically used as a verb in actual sentences. As an example, in the first clause of the previous sentence, "to be" is a noun phrase, whereas "is" (the conjugated form of "to be") is the verb.

Comment: @Ray "To be" is not a noun phrase  - unless you subscribe to one of those types of grammar that are incapable of distinguishing word and phrase categories from their grammatical relations!

Comment: @Araucaria-him You're probably right; I couldn't think of a more precise label to put on it. But "to be" is serving the role of a noun in the phrase "X is not Y", rather than the verb. (So yes, I suppose I was speaking only in terms of grammatical relations there.) And more to the point, it rarely if ever serves the role of a verb in any sentence it appears in, despite being the name of a particular class of verbs

Comment: I don't think I can answer the question, but I want to note that the Japanese word for "is" (desu) is generally not considered a verb, either by English linguists or Japanese ones. It falls into its own class of words, called "copula", because it behaves syntactically differently from verbs.

Comment: @Tvde1 I am asking the community of stackexchange. I come from a background where the definition of a term is something that's agreed on by community consensus, with the caveat that there is some justification behind such definitions i.e. we take this as the definition of such and such, because it allows us to make intellectual progress in the following way. So implicitly I am asking to view a discussion between people who know more than I do on the topic (or at least claim to), so that I can learn from it. Authority is not required.

Comment: @N.Virgo I have seen this word copula before, and in English "is" is considered a copula. My understanding is that copulas are a subcategory of verbs though (in English anyway).

Comment: @user3273084 maybe so - I'm not familiar with the term outside of Japanese. But anyway the copula in Japanese isn't considered a verb, as it's grammatically different from verbs.

Comment: @Tvde1 He is not asking for the word to be defined prescriptively, he is just asking what are the boundaries of meaning within which the word is generally used and accepted.

Answer (score 26):

It's important to draw a distinction between *syntax* and *semantics*.

In *syntax* (how words fit together), words are put into "categories" based on the way they fit together with others. If I give you the sentence "the dog is happy", then:

- You can replace the word "the" with "a" or "my" or "this" or…
- You can replace the word "dog" with "cat" or "bug" or "sandwich" or "plant" or…
- You can replace the word "is" with "was" or "seems" or "looks" or "becomes" or…
- You can replace the word "happy" with "sad" or "purple" or "viscous" or "numinous" or…

As long as you replace a word with another word from the same category, the sentence seems to hold together, even if it doesn't make much sense. But if you swap in a word from another category, it falls apart: *"sandwich this purple looks" isn't valid English.

Based on criteria like this, syntacticians call the words in the first category *determiners*, and words in the second category *nouns*, and words in the third category *verbs*, and words in the fourth category *adjectives*.

You can also subdivide these categories more finely. For example, some verbs want one noun after them (hits), while others want two (gives), and others want none (rests). "Verbs" is a broad label covering all of these and more.

In *semantics* (the study of meaning), the word "verb" isn't generally used. Instead, semanticists will use terms like "predicate" to refer to something that can be true about an entity, regardless of what words are used to express it.

Comment: Could you explain why _hits_ "wants one noun after it" and _gives_ two? _Alice gives blood_ and _Bob hits people_ both seem perfectly valid sentences.

Comment: @terdon Most verbs in English can be adapted to take fewer objects, but you can't say, for example, *_Bob hits people a stick_. One of the rare verbs that can't seem to take fewer than its appointed number of objects is "put": *_Alice puts_, *_Alice puts the plate_.

Comment: It's important to distinguish grammatical category and function. 'Verb' is a word category (part of speech) and verb phrase is its phrasal counterpart. Predicate, on the other hand, is a function typically realised by a verb phrase (category). Note that the function of the verb in a VP is 'predicator', the head of the VP.

Answer (score 7):

Semantically, there are two main functions in language: reference and predication. Some morphological items or words primarily refer to entities in the perceived world, while other items relate the role of each entity in a state of facts. Typically, nouns, pronouns and determiners implement the reference function. The predication function is carried out primarily by means of verbs and, to a lesser extent, through adjectives.

Verbs are the words or morphological items which, in conjunction with some additional elements, express [tense-aspect-mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tense%E2%80%93aspect%E2%80%93mood). In some languages (e.g. Lummi, Nahuatl, ...) many items can function as verb in the sense of taking personal marks. In Nahuatl:

(1) *in cihuatl* 'the woman' / *ni-cihuatl* 'I am a woman'

(2) *ni-mitz-maka-z* (1sgSUB-2sgOBJ-give-FUT) 'I will give you'

we can see here that the article *in* with *cihuatl* 'woman', but the same item can take the personal mark *ni-* (1st sing.), the same mark which appear in a typical verb as *maka* 'give'. This suggest that syntactically a verb is word/item performing an instance of predication function. So maybe it is not correct to assume that the class of verbs and the class of nouns are disjoint classes. What makes *cihuatl* a verb or a noun is the type of environment in the sentences.

Comment: Your example with *cihuatl* is an interesting one. It reminds me a bit of English which has words like "mother", "saw", "frame" which are either verbs or nouns. But of course, it's more productive in Nahuatl than in English. By the way, what's with the hyphens? Most Nahuan orthographies just write the morphemes together, like *nicihuatl* or *nimitzmakaz*.

Comment: @OmarL I'm having trouble thinking of English words that can be used only as a noun or only as a verb.  Can you help me with an example?

Comment: @phoog what about "exemplify" or "tarpit"

Comment: @OmarL thanks.  Of course, it's fairly trivial to imagine someone using _tarpit_ to mean _put into a tarpit_ (perhaps for reasons of homicide) or _end up in a tarpit_ (as in "these fossils were tarpitted a few million years earlier").  Also "tarpit" as a verb seems to have some currency in cybersecurity ("Another possible solution to this sort of attack is known as tarpitting, sometimes known as a sticky honeypot").  _Exemplify_ is a bit harder; my searches turn up scanning errors, mostly.  But if "spend" can be a noun, surely there's a context in which "exemplify" can be, too.

Comment: @OmarL It's to show what the morphemes are!

Answer (score 5):

What's a verb? It's different in every language. In English, I can see how you don't want to put *is* and *leaves* in the same category. And you're right about why *is* is considered a verb. But it's not just to make the rule work -- the rule describes the way people talk -- you gotta have an inflected form of *be* as an auxiliary for

- every predicate adjective (*He's short/tired/finished/asleep/gone*)
- every predicate noun (*That's the president/sand/a hamburger/a clue*)
- every passive construction (*He was hit by a truck, She was interviewed yesterday*)
- every progressive construction (*He's flying over, It's roasting now*).

The fact is, every clause in English **does** have a verb in it, although if the only verb is *be*, it acts like an auxiliary rather than a lexical verb, since it doesn't have any meaning.

And not all verbs are actions. Many are, but many are states. For instance, *rent* is an active verb, but *own* is a stative verb. You can tell because the progressive can only occur with actives:

- *I'm renting that house now.*
- **I'm owning that house now.*

You can't define a verb by what it means, because there are too many ways to mean; it has to be by use. In English, verbs can be distinguished by their inflections (past tense *-ed*, gerund *-ing*, 3rd person singular present *-s*) and by their use in a clause.

Comment: "I was renting that house last year, but I am owning it now" = acceptable English, surely?

Comment: @fdb Not in the standard English of most English-speaking regions of the world. It's probably acceptable in standard Indian English.